# How can I get the list of user accounts that Windows presents on the Log-On screen?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm using NetQueryDisplayInformation (I've already tried the NetUserEnum function) to get the set of user accounts on the local machine.  I can get all the accounts this way - but I only want the accounts associated with actual human beings, and not, for example, hidden accounts used for software updates.

After reading [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370684%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the relevant structures and [similar Stack questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417409/enumerating-windows-log-in-screen-user-accounts-in-vb6), I see nothing that can allow me to filter to just the accounts that I need.

Ideally, someone will have a simple and reliable solution that:

1. Doesn't involve using undocumented registry entries
2. Doesn't rely on enumerating user folders on disk
3. I'm not going to try to build an exhaustive list of non-real-user accounts
4. For technical reasons, WMI is not an option

Any ideas?

[Much later]
Got the answer, but not here - just enumerate the groups for each user.  "Real human" accounts will be a member of one or more of Administrator, Power User, User, Guest.

Comment: Is this information not available in the usri1_flags field?

Comment: Read the documentation, tried a few combinations of bits, but nothing worked.  Still got too many users.

Comment: With the hope that this will help you find the right place to look...  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList\<Username>`  That registry entry is a DWORD.  IF it's 0, the user won't show up on the welcome screen

Comment: Thanks @JimR, I've head of that one.  The thing is that non-human users like "Updateus" don't have an entry there - but are silent nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the [NetUserEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It should return a list of all the user accounts on the system. I've not had to use this function personally so I can't provide any spectacular code examples, but the MSDN information sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Already tried that, and also the very similar NetQueryDisplayInformation.  They do list all users, but unfortunately the set of users who'll actually be shown on the Windows log-on screen is only a subset of what these methods give.  Essentially, I've got too much data, and I'm tried to whittle it back to just the "real human" users.

Comment: Good point @Anders; not as concerned about that.  My main concern is just not to confuse our users by showing them unfamiliar user-names like "autoupdater" or the like.

Comment: Turns out the secret is to display only users that belong to at least one of Administrator, Power Users, Users, or Guests

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetQueryDisplayInformation API,  combine with bitwise check on user info flag.

I have exactly the same requirements, so I cook sample code (modified from MSDN GROUP query).

The user flags I used are:

```
UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT
UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE
UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD ---> this ensure we get Human account, Human account always requires password.
```

working code at: http://www.cceye.com/list-system-normal-user-account-only/